# How to detect edges using Canny in Android in low brightness and ignore shadows?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, android, canny-operator, opencv

I'm developing an Android application to perform image segmentation using Opencv in real time.

The problem is when I applied Canny edge detector, there is always gaps in detected contours even in high brightness environment but detection is accurate when I turn on my smartphone flash.

And when I turn on flash, shadows are also detected which isn't good for my purposes.

I tried to enhance pixels values using Opencv method `convertTo` and I tried also increasing camera `exposure`, but in vain.

Here is my code

```
        Imgproc.cvtColor(orr, orr, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);

        Core.split(orr, channels);

        orr = channels.get(1);

        //orr.convertTo(orr, orr.type(), 1.1);

        Core.meanStdDev(orr, mu, stddev);

        CLAHE clahe = Imgproc.createCLAHE();

        clahe.setClipLimit(1);

        clahe.apply(orr, orr);

        clahe.collectGarbage();

        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(orr, orr, new Size(5, 5), 3);

        Imgproc.Canny(orr, orr, mu.get(0, 0)[0], stddev.get(0, 0)[0], 3, false);


        Imgproc.morphologyEx(orr, orr, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, kernell);

        Imgproc.dilate(orr, orr, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_CROSS, new Size(3, 3)));

        Imgproc.findContours(orr, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        for (int i = contours.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            double area = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i), false);  //  Find the area of contour
            if (area < min_area || contours.get(i).width() >= orr.width() / 3)
                contours.remove(i);
        }


        if (contours.size() > 0) {
            MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();
            rectList.clear();
            for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {
                //Convert contours(i) from MatOfPoint to MatOfPoint2f
                MatOfPoint2f contour2f = new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(idx).toArray());
                //Processing on mMOP2f1 which is in type MatOfPoint2f
                double approxDistance = Imgproc.arcLength(contour2f, true) * 0.02;
                Imgproc.approxPolyDP(contour2f, approxCurve, approxDistance, true);

                //Convert back to MatOfPoint
                MatOfPoint points = new MatOfPoint(approxCurve.toArray());

                // Get bounding rect of contour
                Rect rectt = Imgproc.boundingRect(points);
                rectList.add(rect);
                Mat miniature = new Mat(orr, new Rect(rectt.tl(), rectt.br()));
                mats.add(miniature);

                // draw enclosing rectangle (all same color, but you could use variable i to make them unique)
                Imgproc.rectangle(rotated, rectt.tl(), rectt.br(), new Scalar(255, 0, 0));
            }
        }

        Imgproc.resize(rotated, rotated, new Size(rotated.width() * 2, rotated.height() * 2));

        long e2 = Core.getTickCount();
        long e = e2 - e1;
        double time = e / Core.getTickFrequency();
```

Here is the image without flash

[image]

And here is the output result with flash

[image]

So my question is what can I do to have accurate detection without using phone flash ?

Comment: Have you tried reducing [`threshold1` and `threshold2`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=canny#canny)?

Comment: Threshold is auto calculated using mean .

Comment: I hear you, but the threshold calculated is not suitable for your purposes. I think you've just demonstrated that. Threshold should be regarded as a tunable parameter, here. After all, you're not using AI; you're using Canny.

Comment: Thank you Sir, but i need it to be generic for most cases, so when I use low threshold, detection is bright places won't work